# MultiThread and Processor's Capacity

Tags: java, multithreading, processor, capacity

I dont understand why I have 4 Threads RUNNING but only 50% of processor's capacity used : indeed that's mean only 2/4 processors are used.

[image]

EDIT : I think this is due to the limit : my mistake is 5 Threads are RUNNING at the same time so by default the System limit the %CPU to 2 cores (50%).
I am going to check about 4 Threads

Comment: Unrelated: only use tags that are relevant for your question. It absolutely does **not** matter what IDE type you are using!

Answer (score 2):

This very much depends on what your threads are **doing**.

If the work they are doing is heavily focused on **IO** operations, then your CPUs can run many many such threads - without getting to any significant CPU load ever.

In other words: most likely, your threads are **not** doing CPU intensive work.

But we can't know for sure, as you are *not* giving any hints about the nature of your application.

Comment: I start 4 Threads "ForkJoinPool".
When a "ForkJoinPool" isDone (State WAIT) then "Thread 1" is running.
Then  alway have 4 Threads in RUNNING State

Note : when I start 3 Threads "ForkJoinPool" at the same time, and "Thread 1" is waiting, I have 75% CPU.

Answer (score 0):

First, it depends on how many CPU cores do you have - if you have more CPU cores than running threads, then there aren't enough threads to keep all the cores in the processor busy at 100%.

Another thing is that a thread can be in a waiting state eg. waiting on monitor and in such case it doesn't consume the CPU cycles.

In your screenshot one of threads from your pool is in MONITOR state - it is not executing at that moment - it is waiting for something, and as such not consuming CPU cycles.

I think that all the threads in your pool are similar and all share the characteristic of having some potential wait on a monitor - and this limits the possibility of consuming all the CPU cores at 100%.

For example, this simple program should consume all of your cores at 100% simply because it doesn't have any waiting, but if you uncomment the line that orders it to sleep 1 nanosecond `Thread.sleep(0, 1);` then you will hardly notice any cpu load.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class consumeMaxOfCPU {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int availableProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        // availableProcessors = availableProcessors /2; // uncomment this line to see around half of the load - because there will be less threads than CPU cores.
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(availableProcessors);
        for (int n = 0; n < availableProcessors; n++) {
            pool.submit(new HeavyTask(n));
        }
    }

    private static class HeavyTask implements Callable<Long> {
        private long n;

        public HeavyTask(long n) {
            this.n = n;
        }

        @Override
        public Long call() throws Exception {
            // there are very little chances that this will finish quickly :)
            while (n != -10) {
                n = n * n;
                //  Thread.sleep(0, 1); // uncomment this line to see almost no load because of this sleep.
            }
            return n;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I start 4 Threads "ForkJoinPool".
When a "ForkJoinPool" isDone (State WAIT) then "Thread 1" is running.
Then  alway have 4 Threads in RUNNING State

Note : when I start 3 Threads "ForkJoinPool" at the same time, and "Thread 1" is waiting, I have 75% CPU.